# How to fix redirect looping in servlet url-pattern like "users/*"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-pattern, redirect-loop

I have a problem with setting url-pattern for servlet. If I set it to something like "users/*", after forwart() or include() to jsp, I get a redirect looping.

Here is my code:

```
@WebServlet("/users/*")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String[] pathParts = request.getPathInfo().split("/");

        int id = Integer.valueOf(pathParts[1]);

        request.setAttribute("userId", id);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("user.jsp").include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Your solutions are really works. I don't know why, but relly works) If you have time, could you please explein me the differents?

Comment: Added the explanation. If you find helpful please mark it as correct which can be further helpful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "/" to your jsp page

```
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

So what made difference here ???

If you directly specify **user.jsp** Server check user.jsp in default directory for example if Tomcat is used as webserver then server checks for user.jsp in /webapp folder (Where all applications resides.).

so where is user.jsp located ??? Its in your application for example "JSPTurorial". If you want reference user.jsp in your application you should give the relative path **"/user.jsp"** so that your server will check here "http://localhost:8080/JSPTutorial/user.jsp" as server is executing the files in /JSPTutorial directory else it will check here "http://localhost:8080/user.jsp"  which will not be available at that path.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your servlet as follow:

```
@WebServlet("/users")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String[] pathParts = request.getPathInfo().split("/");

        int id = Integer.valueOf(pathParts[1]);

        request.setAttribute("userId", id);
       getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```